# A ball game riddle

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic, puzzle

Consider the following riddle:

> A ball game is played where the players can score with their feet (for
>   $x$ points) or with their hands (for $y>x$ points). We know that $91$
>   scores are impossible, and among those is the score 48.
>
> **What
>   are the values of $x$ and $y$ ?**

*Note:* This is just for pleasure. I have a solution but am looking for the most elegant and concise alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $x$ and $y$ must be co-prime, otherwise there would be an infinite number of impossible scores. For the co-prime case, the Wikipedia article on the [Coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) gives $(x-1)(y-1)/2$ as the number of non-representable integers (see [Frobenius number for $n=2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#n_.3D_2)). So $(x-1)(y-1)=182=2\cdot7\cdot13$.

Therefore $x-1$ must be a factor of $182$: $x-1=1,2,7,13,14,26,91,$ or $182$. So $(x,y)$ is one of:
$$(2,183)$$
$$(3,92)$$
$$(8,27)$$
$$(14,15)$$
$$(15,14)$$
$$(27,8)$$
$$(92,3)$$
$$(183,2)$$

We are given that $48$ is an impossible score, which rules out $2, 3,$ and $8$. So we are left with $(x,y)=(14,15)$ or $(15,14)$.

Comment: It says y>x in the question, so we are left with (x,y) = (14,15) :) Great solution! +1